# Is it possible to edit documents using the Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I need to create weekly texts using the same template. Being the lazy programmer I am I wanted to automate most of it by just creating a Google Form where I can input the data. By then running a PHP script I want to parse the new entry and put it into an automatically created new document.

I have created the template with placeholders such as `<DATE>` or `<NEWMEMBERCOUNT>` that I later want to replace by the values entered using the Google Form.

For this I have already utilized the packages *[google/apiclient](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/)* and *[asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client)* to read the form results (which are stored in a spreadsheet) and duplicate the template doc for each entry.

I'm almost finished and just need to replace the placeholders by their corresponding values, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Specifically I need to read the content of the document, perform some transformations on it (i.e. replacing the placeholders) and save it with this transformed text.

I should have thought about this before starting to program it..

Is it possible for me to edit documents at all, using just PHP? If so, how could I go about it? Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: At one point there was a gdata api for editing documents but it was shutdown and replaced by Google drive api which doesn't let you edit files.    google spreadsheets data api is still live

Comment: But I don't take it the Spreadsheets Data API is able to edit docs? Also, does _still_ alive mean they're planning to shut it down too?

Comment: I don't think they will shut down sheets until they have something else.  No I don't think sheets api can edit anything but a sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit in situ, but you can download, edit, upload. Is this a classic mailmerge, ie. take a spreadsheet containing (rows of) data, apply a template to those rows that results in an output file for each row?

If so , simples...

- Download the spreadsheet
- Download the template
- For each spreadsheet row

  - replace the placeholders with data
  - insert a new file to drive

That can all be done with the Drive API from PHP

Comment: I've done it this way now. The template is a docx file (which is basically a zip), but I could just unzip, replace its contents and re-zip it before uploading it again. Will be a little more difficult adding (un)ordered lists in there, but that's another matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible with anything except google apps script. see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app

you can use apps script to create a "contentService" and call it from your php. beware of limited quotas if you plan to have many daily calls.

more info about doing this content service is covered in other s.o. questions that ask that specifically.